# Bash shell how to remove string from array with -= operator

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm doing my first bash project for class (so this should be basic stuff yet I am struggling a bit) and I have to have 2 functions where from one I can add "-" in front of an already existing string and the second function removes the previously placed "-" from the string, the issue is that I can't remove "-" with operator -= but I can easily add it with +=, why doesn't the -= operator work the same as += ?

The main focus is the remove function. I'm pasting the full code for reference but the main issue I want to resolve is how to remove "-" from a string that I previously added because -= is not working for me.

Thank you guys in advance.

P.S. I'm using onlinegdb

```
    array_cap=( "Classroom 1" "Classroom 2" )


add () {
    
    echo "Current capacity of classrooms:"
    
     n=${#array_cap[@]}
    n=$((n-1))
    for (( i = 0; i <= $n; i++ ))
    do
    echo -e " "${array_cap[i]}" \n" 
done
    
    echo "Enter the name of the student you want to add"
    
    read student_input
    
    
    echo "Enter the class you want to add the student to:"
    read classrom_input
    for i in "${!array_cap[@]}"; do
   if [[ "${array_cap[$i]}" == "${classrom_input}" ]]
   
   then
   echo "Succesfully added $student_input to "${array_cap[$i]}""
   a=" -"
   array_cap[i]+=$a
    fi
    done
    
    echo
    echo "Current capacity of classrooms:"
    
     n=${#array_cap[@]}
    n=$((n-1))
    for (( i = 0; i <= $n; i++ ))
    do
    echo -e " "${array_cap[i]}" \n" 
done
    
}

remove () {
   
      
    echo "Current capacity of classrooms:"
    
     n=${#array_cap[@]}
    n=$((n-1))
    for (( i = 0; i <= $n; i++ ))
    do
    echo -e " "${array_cap[i]}" \n" 
done
    
    echo "Enter the name of the student you want to remove"
    
    read student_input
    
    
    echo "Enter the class you want to remove a student from:"
    read classrom_input
    for i in "${!array_cap[@]}"; do
   if [[ "${array_cap[$i]}" == "${classrom_input}" ]]
   
   then
   echo "Succesfully removed $student_input to "${array_cap[$i]}""
   a=" -"
   array_cap[i]-=$a
    fi
    done
    
    echo
    echo "Current capacity of classrooms:"
    
     n=${#array_cap[@]}
    n=$((n-1))
    for (( i = 0; i <= $n; i++ ))
    do
    echo -e " "${array_cap[i]}" \n" 
done
}
```

Comment: check https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: bash does not have a `-=` operator for array manipulation. Where did you find a documentation, whcih suggests that such an operator would exist? AFIK, array elements can be removed using `unset`.